# Cometchat 5.6 + Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I implemented cometchat with codeigniter, but it only shows cometchat bar in the bottom of my page for a few second and then dissappear.

in the Page Info it shows cometchat icon component in my page.

I already tried clearing cookies and caches in browser , and deleting cometchat/cache folder.

**EDIT** :I am  playing around with it and it seems cometchat.js always return CCReceiveError but i don`t know why.

Comment: Why don't you contact their team at https://www.cometchat.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a `getUserID()` configuration issue. The ready integration of **CometChat** for codeigniter uses the `ci_session` cookie to identify the logged in user. Modifying the `getUserID()` function (in /cometchat/integration.php) depending on how you have programmed your site should fix the issue.

For any other assistance please create a support ticket [here](https://my.cometchat.com/tickets)

Comment: i already get GetUserID()
i think it was chatLogin($userName,$userPass) that make the problem.

where did $userPass comefrom ? ? ?

Comment: Hi Namikaze Sheena,                                                                                                                                                                   If you are using the Mobile apps or Desktop Messenger, then the $userPass will be the password entered by the user when he tries to login. You need to add relevant code here to check if these details are correct. If you are not using the apps/messenger, then you do not need to worry about this.